# Resizing the ToolBar icons

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, dimension

Good day

I have a basic toolbar to which I added ImageIcon buttons. The images are however different in size.
How would I go about in resizing the Icons so that they are all the same size.

```
super("ToolBar");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //creating the icons for the toolbar
    ImageIcon savePic = new ImageIcon("c:/Exercises/unitTwo/Chapter Three/Images/save.png");
    ImageIcon openFilePic = new ImageIcon("c:/Exercises/unitTwo/Chapter Three/Images/open.png");
    ImageIcon printPic = new ImageIcon("c:/Exercises/unitTwo/Chapter Three/Images/print.png");



    //creating buttons with initial text and icons. I.o.w. the buttons for the toolbar are created

    JButton save = new JButton("Save", savePic);
    JButton open = new JButton("Open", openFilePic);
    JButton print = new JButton("Print", printPic);


    JToolBar bar = new JToolBar();
    bar.add(save);
    bar.add(open);

    bar.add(new JToolBar.Separator());
    bar.add(print);

    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(10, 40);


    add(BorderLayout.NORTH, bar);
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, text);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Use some image editor like Gimp (http://www.gimp.org/) to edit the images outside of your program.

Comment: Given there are slews of icon libraries available (each providing icons of identical width & height) for things like save, open and print, I would tend to use one of those sets than attempting to adapt some images using a paint program or at run-time.  Resizing such small images often results in a horrid icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flamingo component suite supports resizable icons, one of the support classes being [ImageWrapperResizableIcon](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.insubstantial/flamingo/7.0/org/pushingpixels/flamingo/api/common/icon/ImageWrapperResizableIcon.java#ImageWrapperResizableIcon). You might try to have a look at the source to get an idea of how to implement automatically resizing icons without the need to manually do so.

Alternatively, just create a resized version of the image yourself and create the `ImageIcon` using that resized version.